# How can I use Control.Lens to update the ith element of a list?

Tags: haskell, lenses

I have some datatypes along the line of

```
data Outer = Outer { _list :: [ Inner ] }
data Inner = Inner { _bool :: Bool }
```

using Control.Lens, I can access the _bool of the ith Inner (inside a 'State Outer' monad) like this

```
boolValue <- gets (^. list . to (!! i) . inner)
```

I would like to also be able to update this value with something like

```
list ^. (to (!! i)) ^. inner %= True
```

However (by my understanding), the 'to' function only creates a getter, not a true lens that can be used as either getter or setter.

So, how can I convert (!! i) into a lens that will allow me to update this field?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't* turn `(!!)` into any lens-like thing other than a `Getter` -- but there's a function to do this sort of thing: [ix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/3.9.0.2/doc/html/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix), for accessing things at indices. It's actually a `Traversal`, not a `Lens` -- which, here, just means that it can fail (if the index is out of bounds) -- but as long as the index is in the list, it'll work.

There's another problem, though -- `(^.)` is also an operator that's used exclusively for getting values. It's incompatible with e.g. `(%=)`, which takes a lens-like thing as its first argument. And: `(%=)` is for mapping a function over the existing value; if you just want to set, you can use `(.=)`. So you probably want something like:

```
list . ix i . inner .= True
```

* There actually is a function that can do this -- it's called `upon` -- but it uses wonderful evil black magic and you shouldn't use it, at least not for this (and probably not for any real code).

Comment: could you clarify what the difference is between `ix` and `element`? I've gone with Gabriel's `element` since it seems simpler, taking an `Int` instead of an `Index`. From the docs you linked, it seems `ix` is more general in what it allows - is it strictly more general?

Comment: I didn't think of `element`. It isn't exactly that one is more general than the other... `ix` is a type class that has a bunch of instances for indexing with particular index types (for example, lists with `Int`, `Map`s with their index type, functions with their domain). `element` takes any `Traversable` type and counts left-to-right with an `Int` index. In this case they happen to coïncide.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I would guess that `ix` is a bit more efficient for this particular case (mostly because I haven't figured out a way to make `Indexing` generate good code... :-( Someone else is welcome to try). It's also a somewhat ad-hoc class.

Answer (score 10):

Use `element`, which is a `Traversal` to the specified list element:

```
list . element i . inner %= True :: Outer -> Outer
```

If you want to get the list element you must do so using a `Maybe` since the list element might not be there:

```
myList :: Outer

myList ^? list . element i . inner :: Maybe Bool
```

Comment: Note that `%=` gives you a `State` action for modifying a state, i.e. `... :: State Outer ()`. (Also, I assume the question meant `.=` here.)

Comment: Yeah, I mean `%~`, but I think your answer is better anyway.